# Setting very very long text on auto sized label inside a UITableview breaks the NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a autosized cell inside a UITableview. I am using AutoLayout and UITableViewAutomaticDimension for row height.

It works perfectly for all the cases, even for pretty long text (2000 words of Lorem ipsum).

But when I set a really long text e.g. 5000 words of Lorem Ipsum, I am getting the text truncated at the end and I get below in log

> This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that
>   exceeds internal limits.  A smaller value will be substituted, but
>   this problem should be fixed. Break on BOOL
>   _NSLayoutConstraintNumberExceedsLimit(void) to debug.  This will be logged only once.  This may break in the future.

Here is my constraints.

[image]

Has anyone faced this problem before? What are the workarounds for this problem.

Comment: Can you show the relevant constraints?

Comment: Are you using the `textLabel` that comes with `UITableViewCell`? Or a custom `UILabel`? Or are you using a `UITextView`? Which one?

Comment: I believe the max height of a UILabel (and possibly other view objects) is 8192. I don't get the error message you're getting -- I'm on iOS 11 - if you are on 12, that may be new. In any case, though, that is a ***LOT*** of text to stuff into a label, and a ***LOT*** of text to scroll through. Are you sure that wouldn't be bad user experience?

Answer (score 0):

You've crossed the maximum size a `UILabel` is able to hold (which annoyingly isn't defined on Apple's docs). If you need text that long, you should use a `UITextView`. To make it behave the same as a `UILabel` make sure you set `isEditable = false`.